# gen_contour_region_xld control parameter error in c#

Tags: halcon

After I developed my code in HDevelop,

```
find_local_deformable_model (ImageReduced1, ImageRectified, VectorField, DeformedContours, ModelID...) 
gen_region_contour_xld (DeformedContours, EdgeRegion, 'margin') 
union1(EdgeRegion, RegionUnion) 
region_features(RegionUnion,['width','height'],WidthAndHeight)
```

It can run, but after I export it to C#, it cannot, reported:
HALCON error #1301: Wrong value of control parameter 1 in operator

When I export it to cpp, it can run also.

What is the problem?

Comment: Hi Ben,
in which operator is the error thrown in C#? Is it in region_features? If yes how is this line exported? In HALCON 19.05 it is exported to `HOperatorSet.RegionFeatures(ho_RegionUnion, (new Tuple("width")).TupleConcat("height"), out hv_WidthAndHeight);`, which works without an error.

Comment: The error is from HOperatorSet.GenContourRegionXld in C#, and in the HALCON watch debug window, I can see the xld object of image of DeformedContours, because it stop, so I cannot go to regionFeatures operator

Answer (score 1):

finaly I find this is a typo, when coding against VS, I made the code install of export, so this introduced a typo, by HOperateSet., it gave me GenContourGeionXld, should be GenRegionContourXld.